# Purpose and outcome of the following PHP

Tags: php, http, soap

Could someone elaborate on the purpose of this code and whether it would function, if so what the outcome would be?

The following is my interpretation of it, please point out where im going wrong.

Firstly, the client.php file; this is storing a name within the $param variable, not quite sure what else its doing... the $response is calling a 'get_message' which im guessing is being stored on the server.php file?

server.php is now creating the get_message function based on what was entered from your_name? it then provides a result of a message including your name...

Sorry if this is wrong, im quite new to this and a brief overview of what is happening would greatly help the overall understanding of it.

client.php

```
<?php
2 require_once (’lib/nusoap.php’);
3 $param = array( ’your_name’ => ’BIA Student’);
4 $client = new nusoap_client(’http://localhost/WebServiceSOAP/server.php’);
5 $response = $client->call(’get_message’,$param);
6 if($client->fault)
7 {
8 echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>";
9 echo "String: ".$client->faultstring;
10 }
11 else
12 {
13 echo $response;
14 }
15 ?>
```

server.php

```
1 <?php
2 require_once (’lib/nusoap.php’);
3 $server = new soap_server;
4 $server->register(’get_message’);
5 function get_message($your_name)
6 {
7 if(!$your_name){
8 return new soap_fault(’Client’,’’,’Put Your Name!’);
9 }
10 $result = "Welcome ".$your_name .". Thanks for calling your
11 first Web Service using PHP with SOAP!";
12 return $result;
13 }
14 if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) )
15 $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( ’php://input’ );
16 // create HTTP listener
17 $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
18 exit();
19 ?>
```

Comment: None of it will do anything, because you have mangled the text throug a word processor. `’` is not a valid string delimiter in PHP, and makes the whole script a syntax error. As for the rest, we're not here to teach you basic PHP. That's up to you to learn: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client.php will create a soap connection to a web service. That client.php then queries that web service to see if a fault has occurred, if it does it displays the fault.

The server.php will responds to the client connection with a fault if no name has been set. If a name has been set, it returns a message however saying welcome and creates a listener.